# c# Changing page did not change back

Tags: c#

When I tapped the icon for the next page its work but when I tapped the previous icon, continue changing for the next page. I think I need to use the SelectedId function.

This is the name of the icon I'm using: grdSpecialPageExerciseIndex

Code:

```
 private void grdSpecialPageExerciseIndex_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      switch (specialbtnId)
        {
            case 0:
                if (specialbtnIndex < lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices.Count() - 1)
                {
                    specialbtnIndex++;
                    LoadSpecialPagesBookExcersices(lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices.ElementAt(specialbtnIndex));
                    txbSpecialPageExerciseNumber.Text = (specialbtnIndex + 1).ToString();
                    txbSpecialPageExerciseNumberCount.Text = lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices.Count().ToString();
                    // btn1SpecialPages.DataContext = lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices.ElementAt(0);
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                if (specialbtnIndex < lstCurrentPageLeftButton2Excersices.Count() - 1)
                {
                    ;
                    specialbtnIndex++;
                    LoadSpecialPagesBookExcersices(lstCurrentPageLeftButton2Excersices.ElementAt(specialbtnIndex));
                    txbSpecialPageExerciseNumber.Text = (specialbtnIndex + 1).ToString();
                    txbSpecialPageExerciseNumberCount.Text = lstCurrentPageLeftButton2Excersices.Count().ToString();
                    // btn1SpecialPages.DataContext = lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices.ElementAt(0);
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                if (specialbtnIndex < lstCurrentPageLeftButton3Excersices.Count() - 1)
                {
                    specialbtnIndex++;
                    LoadSpecialPagesBookExcersices(lstCurrentPageLeftButton3Excersices.ElementAt(specialbtnIndex));
                    txbSpecialPageExerciseNumber.Text = (specialbtnIndex + 1).ToString();
                    txbSpecialPageExerciseNumberCount.Text = lstCurrentPageLeftButton3Excersices.Count().ToString();
                    //btn1SpecialPages.DataContext = lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices.ElementAt(0);
                }
                break; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little bit confused. If you are routing the event_click from you next and previous button on the same method, you will have the same execution/logic. In this case, how work the **specialbtnId**? If it increase this method Always will go to the next page.

I will recomend you to look to a [NavigationWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Frame](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation) to get a navigation logic.

Or simple with a ContentControl. In a ContentControl, you simply can add in *Content* a Page or a UserControl and so you can override every time the Content. But here you don't have a back navigation. You probably must do it yourself.